# Wallet Pass Push Notification Service

Tags: apple-push-notifications, wallet

I have created service to offer the **brands** to create **appointment passes** and send via email, brands can create passes and send notification using my service.

This service allows them to **send push notifications** and using their **brand name** Can someone suggest as per attached image it’s in conflict or not

[image].

Answer (score 0):

This clause authorizes your customers to send you their certificates for your service to manage on their behalf.  This is a good thing and what you want them to do.

If I read between the lines, I believe you are asking if your service can your own single certificate to send to multiple brands. Attachment 5 to the Developer Agreement states:

> You may use the Pass Type ID only for purposes of digitally signing
>   Your Pass for use with Wallet and/or for purposes of using the APN
>   service with Your Pass. You may distribute Your Pass Type ID as
>   incorporated into Your Pass in accordance with Section 2 below only so
>   long as such distribution is under Your own trademark or brand. To the
>   extent that You reference a third party’s trademark or brand within
>   Your Pass (e.g., a store coupon for a particular good), You represent
>   and warrant that You have any necessary rights. You agree not to
>   share, provide or transfer Your Pass Type ID to any third party
>   (except for a Service Provider and only to the limited extent
>   permitted herein), nor use Your Pass Type ID to sign a third party's
>   pass.

This strongly suggests you should only use your certificate for passes bearing your own trademark or brand.

It's a grey area. Only you can really decide whether or not you want to risk having your certificate revoked.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification, I'm using organization ID to pass their brand name, also made sure in TOS they are agreed to authorize me to use their branding.